# How to use the Three20 for scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, three20, dynamic-loading

i want to display many images and button on each image in a scroll view. and i want the images loaded which are only visible if the user scrolls i want do load the images dynamically. so can i use the  [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) code how to see the actual code for making tiles
in Three20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Three20 can do that. If I remember correctly, you need to subclass [TTPhotoSource](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTPhotoSource.h) and implement code to load the image on-demand from the server.

Interesting classes regarding internet-aware TableViews are TTTableViewDataSource and TTTableViewController Sorry, can't post links for these. New users like me are limited to one link per post.

You find them on Github too. Just look at the "/src/Three20UI/Headers/"-directory